# How to check whether a link is safe or not?

Tags: web-application, web-browser, http, url-redirection

I've been working on a task to find threats in a social network called *Skyrock*. For which, I've managed to retrieve a significant amount of URLs by crawling various user profiles and parsing the data for URLs. These URLs basically are a part of data, that some of the users share publicly on the network. Now, I want to check whether any of these URLs is malicious or not.

I know there are a lot of online url scanners available on the internet to scan for a malicious link, but don't want to use any of those. Instead, I want to use information which am able retrieve about a URL, using some third party API, for example: **location** (lat, long), **url redirects**, **redirect count**, **DNS entries** etc. Can any of these properties be used to check if a particular URL is malicious or not? What other information about a link do I need to check if it's malicious or not?

Note: A malicious link, in this case, could be a link to a phishing site, a spam link, or either a link that makes you download some malware. I just want to know what properties related to a link are useful in figuring out whether a link falls under these categories of malice or not.

Comment: http://urlquery.net reveal reason why it detect a url as bad.

Comment: Okay. But can I use the information that I already have to manually conclude whether it's malicious or not?

Comment: What kind of malice are you looking for? URLs that attempt to get you to download malware? URLs that compromise the security of Skyrock? URLs that are phishing sites?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Online URL scanners have three methods to check URLs for being malicious:

1. Blacklists of known bad URLs. Someone reported that very URL as malicious and entered it into a database. These cases are trivial to check for the scanner but require constant effort to keep the database up-to-date. Considering that many malware-serving websites only exist for hours before they get removed by the hoster or get "un-hacked" by their *real* admin, they outdate very quickly.
2. Known malware samples. They download the linked website and then use a database of known web-based exploits to search for signature strings in it which hint that it is using one. The half-life time of such database entries is much longer than that of URLs, because there are some widely-used stock exploits which are deployed over and over again on thousands of URLs. This method does not help against zero-day exploits and might be fooled by self-written exploits for known vulnerabilities or running stock-exploits through an obfuscator.
3. Heuristics. By analyzing the HTML code and executing dynamic content in a sandbox they can find suspicious behavior and report it. Just like with normal virus scanners, the potential for false-positives is very high.

Note that the methods 2 and 3 aren't foolproof. The malicious website could try to detect that it is downloaded by the URL scanner and serve different content than it would serve to a regular visitor.